# Can't get 3 different responses with "if" or "else" in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to get 3 different responses with "if" and/or "else" when trying to guess a number between 1 and 10. Response #1 should be that you guessed the correct number. Response #2 should be that you guessed the correct number but stayed within the parameters of the question. Lastly, response #3 is that you got the wrong answer but you failed to follow the instructions.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() 
{
    char Response = '\0';
    int RandNum = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));

    RandNum = (rand() % 10) + 1;

/*You have to geuss the correct number between 1-10. If you choose the correct answer then result #1 would play. If you geussed
the wrong answer, but stayed withen the confines of a number between 1 and 10, you would get result #2 would play. And lastly if 
you geussed the wrong answer, but the answer was not a number between 1 and 10, then result #3 would play*/

        printf("\n\tGeuss the number.\n");
        printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10: \n");
        scanf("%c", &Response);

    //You geussed the correct number
    if (Response == RandNum){
        printf("You chose the correct number");
    }

    //Response = a # and 1 <= Response <= 10
    //you geussed the wrong number, but withen the designated parameters
    if ((Response != RandNum) && (Response >= 1 && Response <= 10)){
        printf("Wrong, but nice try\n");
        printf("%d was the correct number.", RandNum);
    }

    //Response != a # or Response > 10 or Response < 1          
    //you geussed the wrong number, but it wasnt withen the designated parameters
    if ((isdigit(Response) == 0) || (Response < 0 || Response > 10)){
        printf("Were you even trying?\n");
        printf("%d was the correct numer.", RandNum);
    }

}
```

Comment: you compare char with int

Comment: So what is your question? State the input, the expected output and the actual output/behaviour.

Comment: `scanf("%c")` --> `scanf(" %c")`. Also that is no good if `10` is an allowed input, you would have to switch to using `%d` (and other associated code changes). And you forget that `'1'` is different to `1`

Comment: well part of my objective was to use `isdigit()` to verify that the user had put in a number and not a character. which is why I have `if ((isdigit(Response) == 0) || (Response < 0 || Response > 10))`, so that I can verify that the user put a number within the perimeter that I set. However, when I run the program no matter what the response is I always get the 3rd result message, "Did you even try". It's as if it skips all of the other options and only uses that one.

Comment: the variable `randnum` can be anything in the range 1...10, so your instructions are wrong as the instructions say `between` 1 and 10 (which equates to 2...9)

Comment: 1) use a logic of `if ... {}  else if ...{}] else {}  2) then this expression in the second `if` will always be true: `(Response != RandNum) &&`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value(s)) to assure the operation was successful.  Note: a integer in the range 1...10 is NOT a character, but a group of bytes (the size of that group will depend on the underlying bus width)  Strongly suggest using the `%d` format specifier, which will not input anything if the input is not digit(s)

Comment: since the call to `scanf()` is using the `%c` format specifier, the input cannot be greater than 1 char long.  (10 would be two characters long)  so any input, what so ever, that begins with any character in the range 1...9 would be accepted.  Not what you want.

Comment: in the posted code, what happens if the input is the character `a`?

Comment: Note: (assuming using ascii characters)  the variable `response` is a character.  so checking the input  `0` (which is 0x30) against 0 (which is 0x00000000 in a 32 bit architecture( will never match.  Similar considerations apply for all the other values the 'response' is being checked against.  Suggest the `response` be declared an integer, not a character

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine to do what you want, what is your question? A more idiomatic approach to what you want to do is chain `if` and `else if` statements.

For example:

```
if (Response == RandNum) {
    //do something
} else if ((Response != RandNum)) && (Response < 10) && (Response > 1)) {
    // do something else
} else if ( ... ) {
    // do another thing
} else {
    // only do this if every other case failed
}
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Be wary of an answer like this.  It is very close to being a comment rather than an answer.  The use of `else` is an appropriate suggestion.  However, there's really no need for the `(Response != RandNum)` term in the first `else if` line.  The alternative is already excluded by the opening `if`, isn't it?

Comment: Trivially fixable: there's one close parenthesis too many after the `RandNum` in the first `else if`.

Comment: This works if I change `Response` to an `int` and dire gard using the `isdigit` function. Which would be ok, but the challenge in my book requires me to use the `isdigit` function. Thanks for the help and reply though!

Answer (score 0):

Note that when the user types `0` into your program, the result in `Response` is `'0'` to `'9'` (corresponding to codes 48 .. 57, usually), which is quite different from 1 to 10.  In fact, there's another problem, too: you can't enter 10 as a single decimal digit.  Further, `Response` is an `int`, not a `char`, so you're passing the wrong type to `scanf()` for the `%c` format.

You should probably be using:

```
if (scanf("%d", &Response) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Didn't get a recognizable integer!\n");
    return 1;  // exit(1); in a function other than main
}
```

This will give you a number to play with.  Consider using `if (…) { … } else if (…) { … } else { … }` for your sequence of tests.  It often makes the logic simpler — it will simplify the logic you need to use.

Note that if you use the `%d` input format as suggested, you won't need to test for `isdigit()`.  If you must use `isdigit()`, then maybe `Response` needs to be a `char` and you do use `%c` after all (but you still check that the read operation worked), but you're left with a conundrum on how to enter 10.

Comment: Yeah I see what you mean now. How then would I make the idea of using the `isdigit` function work? The challenge in my book calls for me to use the `isdigit` function to validate that the user input a number between 1 and 10? One idea I had was to just use `isdigit (Response) + 1` but that gave me whatever the user imputed in its ascii form + 1. Another idea I tried was to use `isdigit(Response) - 48` thinking ok well if I just subtracted the ascii value by 48 that would work but again it didn't get me the results I was after, and as you stated there's the whole issue with the user entering 10

Comment: Does coding `10` as `A` (or `a`) as in hex get around the problem of a single character for `10`?  The specification doesn't make much sense; if you need to be able to enter `10`, then a single character doesn't work.  I suppose you could do an encoding: enter `0` .. `9` to mean `1` .. `10`.  But that's pretty absurd too — and going to lead to confusion for any user of your program ("Enter a number 0..9 to mean a value 1..10:"?). Can you interpret it as an open-closed range `[1..10)` (so only values `1` .. `9` are OK? Or as a closed-closed range `(1..10)` (so only values `2` .. `9` are OK)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check whether the input is a digit or not, your range should be 0 to 9. 10 is a number not a digit.

And if user gives 10 as input, it will only stores 1 in Response variable because you can't store a number with more than 1 digit(here character) in one character variable.

Now from the coding perspective, if you want to check whether the input is a digit or not, you should compare the value stored in Response variable with the ASCII values of 0 to 9 digits as following:

```
if(Response>=49 && Response <= 57) //49 and 57 are ASCII values of 1 & 9 respectively
```

You are checking with 1 & 10, that's why it's always goes to 3rd result message.

To check whether the input is 10 or to compare Response with Integer RandNum, some modifications is required in your current logic as follows:

First of all, declare Response as char pointer as you want to store more than on char in it.

```
char *Response;
printf("\n\tGeuss the number.\n");
    printf("Enter a number between 1 and 10: \n");
    scanf("%s", Response);
```

Now to compare Response with RandNum, you need to add 48(ASCII value of 0 to RandNum and check with Response as Response implicitly converted into int by compiler.

Off course, above logic works only if RandNum!=10.

Hence,

```
   if(RandNum!=10)
     {       
     if ((RandNum+48) ==(int)*Response)
        printf("You chose the correct number");

      else if(Response=="10"||((int)Response[0] >= 49 && (int)Response[0] <=57)) {
       printf("Wrong, but nice try\n");
       printf("%d was the correct number.", RandNum);
       }
        else {                //no need check conditions here
             printf("Were you even trying?\n");
            printf("%d was the correct numer.", RandNum);
            }

     }

     else {         // if RandNum=10

          if(Response=="10")
             printf("You chose the correct number");

         else if((int)Response[0] >= 49 && (int)Response[0] <=57)) {
       printf("Wrong, but nice try\n");
       printf("%d was the correct number.", RandNum);
       }
       else {                //no need check conditions here
         printf("Were you even trying?\n");
            printf("%d was the correct numer.", RandNum);
            }
         }
```

I know it is a little bit complex but so does the requirements!!

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Ok that makes sense. Well do you have any ideas on how I could check for 10?

Comment: @TopherWilmoth if use of isdigit() is mandatory than check it right after reading Response from user(after scanf()) and if it's digit than only check all the given conditions.

Comment: @TopherWilmoth is it helpful?